# PHP: Adding security with http referer

Tags: php, http-referer

Im Kinda A Noob With PHP,
I want to keep my page accessible only from a link
etc. I only want to allow people who clicked a link to my page from example.com

and others like from google.com to redirect to another page on my site etc. a error message

How Could I Do This?

Comment: modern browsers will happily respect a user's DNT (do-not-track) setting, which means that even if they click from google, your server will not be told it was a referral click. You *can* filter that way, but it won't really be reliable. If you want links that only work on your own site, look at adding CSRF to your requests (through cookies, for instance)

Comment: Then How Can I Do This?

Comment: What have you tried? Is there any code that you've attempted that you can post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    $referer_host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
else
    $referer_host = '';
if($referer_host != 'example.com')
{
    header('Location: http://example.com/error');
    exit;
}
```

People not sending (correct) referers for various reasons will be entirely excluded from your page.

Of course bookmarking your site etc. will also not work.

As headers can be faked by the client at will, I would not call this a "security" feature.

Comment: Be aware the HTTP_REFERER is not always set and will throw a notice if you try to access it. Might want to use isset() or use a getter function http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Arr#get